# Error Loading Visual Studio Universal Template

Tags: visual-studio, uwp, uap

I have VS Community 2015 Update three installed. I am trying to learn UWP but I keep getting the following error when trying to launch

[image]

One thing I noticed is that all the videos and screenshots I've seen online say "Universal" and mine says "UAP" uner "Installed\Templates\VisualC#\Windows\

[image]

This is what I have installed:

[image]

I do not have any problems opening any other templates, only the "UAP". I've been using this program all the while but with basic c# console applications. Moving to UWP now and this is what I'm faced with.

Things I've tried:

1. Uninstalling and Reinstalling nugget manager
2. Repairing VS installation in  control panel.

Thank you in advance for your suggestions.

P.S I'm on Windows 10 Pro 14393.222

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by totally uninstalling visual studio with a /uninstall /force

All the sdks and emulators were uninstalled as well.

Launched a new install from the ISO file and everything is fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can try this one -

Run the visual studio installer again. Select **Modify** in the Installer. Select Features - "**Windows and Web Development**" - "**Universal Windows App Development Tools**". Now try to **Update**. It doesn't guarantee that it will solve the problem. But on few machines it worked..